# Hibernate is not saving data?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

My session is working but not saving data in database ..What should I missing..?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMVhl.png)

Comment: Please add the code in the question instead of sharing a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You have not opened any transaction so the changes won't be reflected in the database.

When you create session using SessionFactory.openSession(), no transaction is created, so your operations are executed outside of transaction context. In order to see your changes, you have to start a new transaction, or perform your operations as a part of ongoing transaction.

Example:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Either use Transaction to save the object or in current scenario make the following change in your configuration file:

```
 <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

Comment: @superman You're welcome !! Please mark the answer as correct and upvote it.